# How to format the name of the logging level

Tags: python, logging, ipython, tornado

When I start IPython, I see logs like this:

```
[I 17:03:59.993 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN:       https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
[W 17:04:00.292 NotebookApp] Terminals not available (error was No    module named terminado)
[I 17:04:00.293 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/oleg
[I 17:04:00.293 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 17:04:00.293 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 17:04:00.293 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Here the levels of messages are slightly formatted, that is, you see `I` instead of `INFO`, `W` instead of `WARNING` etc. In addition, the brackets are colored. I find this cool and would like to write my logs that way too. However, IPython uses tornado logging system.

I use the [colorlog module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorlog) to color the messages. In order to do the formatting, I subclassed the `StreamHandler` class, as described here:
 [How to get the level of the logging record in a custom logging.Handler in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061924/how-to-get-the-level-of-the-logging-record-in-a-custom-logging-handler-in-python)

```
class FormatLevelHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        record.levelname = record.levelname[0]
        logging.StreamHandler.emit(self, record)
```

But when I do this, coloring does not work anymore.

Is there a way to have both logging level name formatting and coloring?
Here is my full code:

```
import logging
from colorlog import ColoredFormatter
formatter = ColoredFormatter(
    "%(log_color)s[%(levelname)1s %(asctime)s] %(reset)s %(blue)s%(message)s",
    datefmt=None,
    reset=True,
    log_colors={
        'DEBUG':    'cyan',
        'INFO':     'green',
        'WARNING':  'yellow',
        'ERROR':    'red',
        'CRITICAL': 'red,bg_white',
    },
    secondary_log_colors={},
    style='%'
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class FormatLevelHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        record.levelname = record.levelname[0]
        logging.StreamHandler.emit(self, record)

ch = FormatLevelHandler()
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.info('Hello')
logger.debug('Hi')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not change the level in `handler.emit()`. Instead, truncate the level in the format string itself using `%(levelname)1.1s` (not `%(levelname)1s` as in your example).

Or you can use the Tornado logging system whether you use the rest of Tornado or not: just call `tornado.log.enable_pretty_logging()` at the start of your program.

Comment: Oh, thanks, both solutions (yours and goncalopp's) worked. The problem was that it was difficult to find out about the formatting specifications for `%s `(while everybody knows them for `%d`). Could you please show their descriptions in Python documentation?

Comment: They're documented in [the same place](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). For `%s`, see footnote 5 at the end of the section.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. While the problem seems quite complex at first, the cause simple: `colorlog` uses the dictionary you provide to match the levelname *after* `Handler.emit`.

Thus, you need to change your dictionary to

```
log_colors={
        'D': 'cyan',
        'I': 'green',
        'W': 'yellow',
        'E': 'red',
        'C': 'red,bg_white',
    },
```